# Building a unified interface for a swap chain in both DirectX 12 and Vulkan

Tags: software-engineering, cross-platform, vulkan, directx12

Most objects in DirectX 12 have natural analogues in Vulkan, e.g.

- `VkInstance` = `IDXGIFactory`
- `VkPhysicalDevice` = `IDXGIAdapter`
- `VkDevice` = `ID3D12Device`
- `VkQueue` = `ID3D12CommandQueue`
- `VkCommandBuffer` = `ID3D12CommandList`

However, when it comes to the swap chain, it's not clear how the entries in `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR` correspond to entries in `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1`.

Clearly, there is not always a 1-1 correspondence, but I would really like to know how I can implement a unified interface for both.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of APIs like DirectX 12 and Vulkan is to minimize CPU overhead, and therefore they have extremely *thin* API abstractions. As such, wrapping them in a low-level API basically defeats their whole purpose.

Furthermore, both DirectX 12 and Vulkan expose more of the underlying hardware behavior, so again by design the application needs to have a lot more context about the overall API usage than older graphics API designs.

As such, if you want to implement both a DirectX 12 and Vulkan version of the same application or engine, then you want to create higher-level abstractions. Not "a function to create a swap chain" but "code module to manage the display/output window/system message loop".